# SQL to select users into groups based on group percentage

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

To keep this simple, let's say I have a table with 100 records that include:

- userId
- pointsEarned

I would like to group these 100 records (or whatever the total is based on other criteria) into several groups as follows:

- Group 1, 15% of total records
- Group 2, 25% of total records
- Group 3, 10% of total records
- Group 4, 10% of total records
- Group 5, 40% (remaining of total records, percentage doesn't really matter)

In addition to the above, there will be a minimum of 3 groups and a maximum of 5 groups with varying percentages that always totally 100%. If it makes it easier, the last group will always be the remainder not picked in the other groups.

I'd like to results to be as follows:

- groupNbr
- userId
- pointsEarned

Comment: do you want a one-time thing where you sort them into groups? Or a procedure that can be run again and again to account for new users? If it is the latter, is it okay to move a user into a new group if you are doing a re-organization? AND: you want to do this with SQL as opposed to PHP or C# or something?

Comment: This would be an ongoing dynamic query with group percentages that change with each query. There wouldn't be an organizational change. It would be more for grouping for other temporary uses. I need to do this in SQL. I forgot to mention that this could be for up to 1 million records at a time.

Comment: Do you want Group 1 to be the first 15% (Say userIDs 1 -15 if there was a hundred) or a random 15% from the group?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question, just expressions of desire.

Comment: The question seems obvious as I am asking how to accomplish this. What would you suggest in the future? Posting same failed SQL asking how to fix it? I guess I'm not sure and need some assistance.

Comment: Good question DancingFool. Random would be preferred but obviously not stated in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this sort of breakup, you need a way to rank the records so that you can decide which group they belong in. If you do not want to randomise the group allocation, and userId is contiguous number, then using userId would be sufficient. However, you probably can't guarantee that, so you need to create some sort of ranking, then use that to split your data into groups. Here is a simple example.

```
Declare @Total int
Set @Total = Select COUNT(*) from dataTable
Select case 
    when ranking <= 0.15 * @Total then 1
    when ranking <= 0.4 * @Total then 2
    when ranking <= 0.5 * @Total  then 3
    when ranking <= 0.6 * @Total  then 4
    else 5 end as groupNbr,
    userId,
    pointsEearned

FROM (Select userId, pointsEarned, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY userId) as ranking From dataTable) A
```

If you need to randomise which group data end up in, then you need to allocate a random number to each row first, and then rank them by that random number and then split as above.

If you need to make the splits more flexible, you could design a split table that has columns like minPercentage, maxPercentage, groupNbr, fill it with the splits and do something like this

```
Declare @Total int
Set @Total = Select COUNT(*) from dataTable
Select S.groupNbr
    B.userId,
    B.pointsEearned

FROM (Select ranking / @Total * 100 as rankPercent, userId, pointsEarned
    FROM (Select userId, pointsEarned, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY userId) as ranking From dataTable) A
    ) B
    inner join splitTable S on S.minPercentage <= rankPercent and S.maxPercentage >= rankPercent
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed to know.